# WordPress wp_navi not passing 'query' var

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type "plot-location" and I am dynamically setting setting the $args array with data from a form. When submitted the form shows the correct results on "page 1" BUT when the pagination links are used all the custom posts are returned.

Set Post type:

```
 add_action('init', 'plot_register');  
 function plot_register() {  
    $args = array(  
        'label' => __('Plots'),  
        'singular_label' => __('Plot'),  
        'public' => true,  
        'show_ui' => true,  
        'capability_type' => 'post',  
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'house-type','with_front' => true ),
        '_builtin' =>  false, 
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'excerpt')  
       );  

 register_post_type( 'plot-location' , $args ); 
 //create cats
 register_taxonomy("plot-development", array("plot-location"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Plot Locations", "singular_label" => "Plot Location", "rewrite" => true)); 
}
```

The Loop:

```
     function property_search(){
              //declare vars

              $area = "";
              $price = "";
              $type = "";
              $beds = "";
              //set the vars
              if(isset($_POST['area']) && !empty($_POST['area']))
                 {
                  $area =  array(
                'taxonomy' => 'plot-development',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => strtolower ($_POST['area'])
                    );
                 }
                 //print_r($area);
              if(isset($_POST['price']))
                 {
                  $price = array('key' => 'plotPrice-meta', 'value' => $_POST['price'], 'type' => 'NUMERIC', 'compare' => '>=');
                 } 
             else{
                  $price = array();
                 }            
              if(isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['type']))
                 {
                  $type = array('key' => 'plotType-meta','value' => $_POST['type'], 'compare' => '=') ;
                 }
             else{
                  $type = array('key' => 'plotType-meta','value' => array('Detached', 'Semi', 'Mews', 'Terraced' ), 'compare' => 'IN');
                 }
              if(isset($_POST['beds']))
                 {
                  $beds = array('key' => 'plotBeds-meta','value' => (int)$_POST['beds'],'compare' => '>=');
                 } 
             else{
                  $beds = array();
                 } 
                 //echo $area.' '.$price.' '.$type.' '.$beds;
       global $post;  
       global $page;          
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

     $args = array(
                   'post_type' => 'plot-location',
                   'tax_query' => array(
                                $area
               ),
                   'posts_per_page' => 5,
                   'paged' => $paged,
                   'meta_query' => array(
                                 'relation' => 'AND',
                                 $price,
                                 $type,
                                 $beds                                     
                              ),

            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_key' => 'plotPrice-meta', 
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'ASC'

                  );

    // the query
    global $wp_query;
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
     if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 



      //the loop -->
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
      $out .= '<hr />';
      $out .= '<div class="plot-search-thumb">';
      $out .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'thumbnail'); 
      $out .=  '</div>';
      $out .=  '<div class="plot-search-cont">';
      $out .=  '<h2 class="plot-title">'.get_the_title().'</h2>'; 
      $cus_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'plot-development' );  
       foreach($cus_terms as $term)
              {
               $ob_id = $term->object_id;
               $term_slug = $term->slug;
               $term_name = $term->name;
              } 
      $out .= '<div style="font-weight: bold;">'.$term_name.'</div>';
      //$out .= '<div class="plot-price"><strong>£'.(int)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'plotPrice-meta', true).'</strong></div>' ;
      $out .= '<div class="plot-price"><strong>£'.number_format ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'plotPrice-meta', true)).'</strong></div>' ;
      $out .=  '<div class="plot-excerpt">'.get_the_excerpt().'</div>';
      $out .= '<div style="margin: 0 20px 0 0; float: left;"><a class="plot-search-link" href="'.get_the_permalink($post->ID).'">MORE&nbsp;INFO</a></div>';
                      $arg = array(
                                   'post_type' => 'dev-location',
                                   'meta_key' => 'dev-title',
                                   'meta_value' => $term_slug,
                                   'posts_per-page' => 1
                                  );
                      $dev = get_posts($arg);
                      wp_reset_postdata();       
      $out .= '<div><a class="plot-search-link" href="/development/'.$dev[0]->post_name.'/">VIEW&nbsp;DEVELOPMENT</a></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: left;"></div>';
      endwhile; 
      //end of the loop -->

      //pagination here -->
      $out .= '<div class="post-navigation">';
      //ob_start();
        if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { 
        $out .= wp_pagenavi( array(
            'echo' => false,
            'query' => $the_query 
        )); 
           } 
      //$out .= ob_get_clean();    
      $out .='</div>';


    else: 
      $out .= '<p>'. _e( 'Sorry, no plots matched your criteria.' ).'</p>';
     endif;
     wp_reset_postdata();
     wp_reset_query();
     return $out; 
      } 
      add_shortcode('property_search', 'property_search');
```

It looks like the 'query' var is not being passed along, can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got round this in the end by storing the $_POST values in a $_SESSION variable.

```
             function property_search(){
                      //declare vars
                      $area = "";
                      $price = "";
                      $type = "";
                      $beds = "";
                      //set the vars
        if(isset($_POST['form_submit']))
           {              
                      if(isset($_POST['area']) && !empty($_POST['area']))
                         {
                          $area =  array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'plot-development',
                           'field'    => 'slug',
                           'terms'    => strtolower ($_POST['area'])
                              );
                         }
                         $_SESSION['ssd_area'] = $area;//worst case empty string

                      if(isset($_POST['price']))
                         {
                          $price = array('key' => 'plotPrice-meta', 'value' => $_POST['price'], 'type' => 'NUMERIC', 'compare' => '>=');
                         } 
                     else{
                          $price = array();
                         }
                         $_SESSION['ssd_price'] = $price;

                      if(isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['type']))
                         {
                          $type = array('key' => 'plotType-meta','value' => $_POST['type'], 'compare' => '=') ;
                         }
                     else{
                          $type = array('key' => 'plotType-meta','value' => array('Detached', 'Semi', 'Mews', 'Terraced' ), 'compare' => 'IN');
                         }
                         $_SESSION['ssd_type'] = $type;

                      if(isset($_POST['beds']))
                         {
                          $beds = array('key' => 'plotBeds-meta','value' => (int)$_POST['beds'],'compare' => '>=');
                         } 
                     else{
                          $beds = array();
                         } 
                         $_SESSION['ssd_beds'] = $beds;

            }
        else{
                  //this needs error checks.
                      $area = $_SESSION['ssd_area'];
                      $price = $_SESSION['ssd_price'];
                      $type = $_SESSION['ssd_type'];
                      $beds = $_SESSION['ssd_beds'];         
            }
```

Would love to see some feedback on this: Is this a hack, will break when? etc..

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: After reviewing my dimness, I should have just used get requests!